# Which option is correct

Tags: polynomials

> If two real polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degrees m ($\gt$ $1$) and n ($\gt$ $0$) respectively,satisfy
>
> $f(x^2 + 1)$ $=$ $f(x)g(x)$
>
> for every $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$,then

Which one is correct

1. $f$ has exactly one real root $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)\ne 0$.
2. $f$ has exactly one real root $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)$ $= 0$.
3. $f$ has m distinct real roots.
4. $f$ has no real root.

I tried using some examples but failed.

Comment: @Mason sorry, it has been edited

Comment: This is only possible when $m = n$. The left hand side is a polynomial of degree $2m$ while the right hand side is a polynomial of degree $m + n$. Polynomials of differering degrees cannot be equal for all real numbers.

Comment: Note that if $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f'(x_0) = 0$, then $f(x_0^2 + 1) = 0$ and $f'(x_0^2 + 1) = 0$, so for (2) to be true, you'd need $x_0^2 + 1 = x_0$...

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $x$ is a root of $f$, then so is $x^2 + 1$. But $|x^2 + 1| > |x|$ for all real numbers $x$. So every real root of $f$ requires the existence of another real root of higher magnitude.